# Debugging Eclipse Core Expressions

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am building an Eclipse E4 RCP Application. I have a menu item that uses a core expression. Is there any way to debug this core expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with E4 yet but in 3.x you can debug the expressions. 
Expressions are derived from class `org.eclipse.core.expressions.Expression`.

Their class names match the expression, e.g. `org.eclipse.core.internal.expression.WithExpression` implements the *with* expression.

Assuming you know the expression type you want to debug, just set a breakpoint in the `evaluate` method of the class.

Be aware that expressions are widely used, so setting a breakpoint condition will save you a lot of breakpoint hits.